# "Sirs" meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

A professor of Anatomy told his students that

> “Ignorance of the human body is the surgeon's cardinal sin, **sirs**!”

I'm not sure about the meaning of "sirs" at the end of the sentence. I'm actually confused about it. Please help me with it. [(Dear) Sirs](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dear-sir-sirs) meaning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's merely a polite way of placing an emphasis on a statement by further addressing who (s)he's speaking to. Like when your mother is laying down the law on you and tacks your name onto the end for emphasis. It's like putting an exclamation point on the end of a sentence.

"Sirs" is a polite way of addressing an audience in a formal setting, because the speaker can't name each student individually.  It seems gender-biased, but in business letter-writing it's merely a general address and not excluding women at all, though it appears and can be construed that way

Comment: So it means that it is merely a way of addressing to the male students in the class like when our mother says, "What are you doing?, Prince!" So sirs here refers to the "Male Students". Ok! i got it! thanks.....

Comment: @Selena No, I don't think it's necessarily referring specifically to the male students, although it can appear that way.  In fact, I can't honestly think of how to address both in this same fashion without diminishing the force of the emotional emphasis.  "Sirs and Madams"? "Madams and Sirs"?  Ugh - so awkward.  Maybe "Ladies and Gentlemen". Can't be said as forceful as "Sirs"

Comment: Did the incident happen in the present day or in a previous century? If the latter, it's likely the students would be all male.

Answer (score 0):

"Sir" is a form of polite address for a man.

(Man holds door open for you.) "Thank you, sir."

In the question's example, one presumes that all the students are male.